# How to group by fields which have specific value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following columns in my table (I'm using postgresql): `parent`, `child`, `status`. Each parent has 1 or 2 children.

I want to select all `parent`s whose first child has status `x` and second child has status `y` or in case there's only 1 child than parent with child with status `x`. For example, a table with the following rows:

| parent | child | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | child1 | x |
| a | child2 | y |
| b | child3 | x |

should return parents `a` and `b`.

I started building the query something like:

```sql
select parent from "mytable"
group by parent
having ...
```

but I don't know how to add the above condition for status within `having` clause.

Comment: How are the children ordered?  By name?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there's no specific ordering between children.

Comment: . . Your question implies that there is because you use "first" and "second".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specified what "first" and "second" means.  Let me assume that is the `child` column.

Then you can use:

```
select parent
from mytable
group by parent
having string_agg(status order by child) in ('x', 'xy');
```